# How can I reset my program? (without using goto)

Tags: c++, loops, reset, goto

Basically I have finished programming a little times tables quiz for my little brother.I am very new to programming and I have no idea how to reset my program back to the start. Can anyone shed some light on this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
 int sum ;  
 int question = 0;
 int Uanswer ;
 int score = 0;
 int *score_pointer = &score;
//============================================================//
 cout<<"= Hello Welcome to Your Times Tables   ="<<endl;
 cout<<"= Please Select A Table To Learn Below ="<<endl;
 cout<<"========================================"<<endl;       
    cout<<"####################################"<<endl;          /* THE MENU */
    cout<<"####|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|####"<<endl;
    cout<<"####################################"<<endl;
//============================================================//
    cout<<">>:";
    cin>> sum;
    cout<<"You Selected "<< sum <<endl;                        /*User Input For Table */
    cout<<"Time to Learn Brain Power Go!"<<endl;                                     
//============================================================//
    while (question  <12){
           question = question +1;
           cout<< question;
           cout<< "x";
           cout<< sum ;
           cout<< "=:";
           cin>> Uanswer;
           int Aanswer = (sum * question);

    if (Aanswer == Uanswer){
      cout<<"Correct: Well done Ben :)"<<endl;
       *score_pointer = *score_pointer+1; 
    } else {
        cout<<"Incorrect: Are you even trying? :("<<endl;
    } 
         }

   //====================================//
      cout<<"Well done You scored " <<  score << " Out of 12"<<endl; /*Tally of total score */
   //====================================//

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your next concept you should learn is how to write functions. Instead of writing all of the code in `main`, you can break your code up into functions. Then you could simply call this function in a loop as many times as you'd like, which would effectively "reset" all the local variables. The absolute **wrong** approach would be to start injecting `goto` statements all over your code.

Comment: A very easy solution, rename your `main()` function to `game()`, then add a new `main()` function that simply calls `game()` in a loop.

Comment: So with that being said do I have to write this code all over again but using these functions?

Comment: Are you writing this code because you need to finish this task or are you writing this code to help with your learning of C++? If the latter, I suggest you read up on how to use functions, and then yes, it would be great practice for you to rewrite the program using this new technique.

Comment: @ Joathan potter so basically something like this while (ans == 'Y) game() ??

Comment: @ Corykrammer a bit of both I would like to have the program working so my brother can use it to help his maths, But also it's helping me learn.Ii will be looking at functions soon in the book i am reading  but i don't want to skip to it thought I would not need them for this program. :(

Comment: No rewrite necessary. Just rename `main` into `myfunc` and add the following line after it: `int main() { return myfunc(); }` and you're done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a do while loop to enclose your code and set the condition to what you want.

```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <string>
  #include <fstream>

  using namespace std;
  int main()
      {
       int flag=1;
       do
         {

          //your code that needs to be repeated 
          //when you need to exit set flag=0 

          } while(flag);
        }
```

Comment: Really struggling, Just tried this and got a bunch of errors.

Comment: @marmaa Which lines did you put within the do while-loop and what are the errors

Comment: maybe add `bool condition = true;` before the `do` to make it more obvious

Comment: @SouravKanta I added the lines from the first comment all the way too just before the return sequence !!!

Comment: @marmaa Thats all right only take the return statement out of the loop and see the while statement as I have editted it now.Try to place the starting of the loop from start of main.

Answer (score 2):

Here is your program in a while loop.  I would also recommend not using endl and instead using \n so you dont have to flush the stream so much.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    bool done = false;
    while (!done) {
        int sum;
        int question = 0;
        int Uanswer;
        int score = 0;
        int *score_pointer = &score;
        //============================================================//
        cout << "= Hello Welcome to Your Times Tables   =" << endl;
        cout << "= Please Select A Table To Learn Below =" << endl;
        cout << "========================================" << endl;
        cout << "####################################" << endl;          /* THE MENU */
        cout << "####|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|####" << endl;
        cout << "####################################" << endl;
        //============================================================//
        cout << ">>:";
        cin >> sum;
        cout << "You Selected " << sum << endl;                        /*User Input For Table */
        cout << "Time to Learn Brain Power Go!" << endl;
        //============================================================//
        while (question < 12){
            question = question + 1;
            cout << question;
            cout << "x";
            cout << sum;
            cout << "=:";
            cin >> Uanswer;
            int Aanswer = (sum * question);

            if (Aanswer == Uanswer){
                cout << "Correct: Well done Ben :)" << endl;
                *score_pointer = *score_pointer + 1;
            }
            else {
                cout << "Incorrect: Are you even trying? :(" << endl;
            }
        }

        //====================================//
        cout << "Well done You scored " << score << " Out of 12" << endl; /*Tally of total score */
        //====================================//
        cout << "\nWould you like to try again? (y/n)";
        char answer;
        cin >> answer;
        tolower(answer);
        if (answer == 'n') done = true;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for trying when i tried to compile this i got the error as follows      Times_Tables2.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
Times_Tables2.cpp:14:10: warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]
     bool done{ false };
          ^

Comment: @marmaa Fixed that for you.  Try the new edit.

Comment: Thank you :) will study it and see how it works !!!!

Comment: @marmaa np glad I could help you.  Its pretty cool you are helping your little brother and even cooler you are trying to do it with learning to program.

Comment: Thanks yeah well I figured might as well practise making something useful i guess.If you could it would be super helpful  I have a few books on the subject and would be nice to have a human contact who I can discuss things with and can give me advice. Do you have an email address we could communicate though?

Comment: @marmaa Sure look me up on facebook if you want to.  I am the guy in AZ.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80897/discussion-between-jason-ball-and-marmaa).